# Extend Partition with separate hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, gparted, partitioning

I have a 128gb Hard Drive with Ubuntu installed. I have a separate blank 120gb hard drive.

How would, extend the 128gb drive?

Comment: You could use LVM, but if either drive fails then all data on both drives is gone. I would suggest moving /home as one option. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Comment: Unless the computer already uses LVM, that option would require either re-installing or doing significant juggling to move the existing installation into LVM. LVM is a good option in that it enables having a single filesystem that's bigger than either disk individually. Using the new space as `/home`, or as a subdirectory of it, is likely to be easier to set up and safer in the event of a disk failure, as oldfred suggests, but less flexible. See [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm) for an introduction to LVM.